# Unable to deploy any x86 Windows version with LiteTouch_x64

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, windows-pe

In MDT 2012 Update 1, I configured task sequences for Windows 7 x86, Windows 7 x64, Windows 2008 R2, and Windows XP (x86). I also generated Windows PE for x86 and x64 versions.

In WDS, both boot images are present in Boot Images folder. Then, when I boot a computer using PXE, I can choose between the two LiteTouch images, and then task sequences are listed the following way:

**LiteTouch_x86**

- Windows 7 x86
- Windows 7 x64
- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Windows XP

**LiteTouch_x64**

- Windows 7 x64
- Windows Server 2008 R2

How could I fix this issue?

Comment: Looks like a problem for [MDT Guy](http://superuser.com/users/183159/mdt-guy)! Not sure if he's seen this yet though.